# Translate Matlab's vector assignment into Python form

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, code-translation

I'm trying to translate some Matlab code into Python (using NumPy). I'm not very familiar with Matlab, and I've encountered a line that I'm having trouble parsing:

```
w(idx(1:p, 1), 1) = v(idx(1:p, 1), 1) - theta;
```

I'd hazard a guess that a `p`-long head of `x` is being used as indices to select `p` entries of `w`, and that those entries in `w` are being replaced by corresponding entries in `v` (less a scalar `theta`).

Messing around in Octave, that seems like an accurate description of what it's doing, but I can't find any documentation to that effect.

In any case, what's the best way to re-write this code in Python? I've looked at the NumPy 'Tentative Tutorial' to try and find an elegant way to do it, and it looks like [this](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-0dffc419afa7d77d51062d40d2d84143db8216c2) might be what I'm looking for. However, I'm having trouble making it look nice, particularly with the assignment operator. Are there any more elegant or Python-idiomatic ways to do this assignment operation?

Comment: What you're saying sounds correct. This might help you with the translation: http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users, but I would think `w(idx(1:p, 1), 1)` becomes `w[idx[:p, 1], 1]` in python

Comment: dont forget zero-based vs. one-based indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically what @Dan wrote in the comments, but accounts for zero-based indexing in python:

```
w[idx[:p, 0], 0] = v[idx[:p, 0], 0] - theta
```

Not sure if you wanted something more elegant than that.  Those zeros are required if only the first column should be modified.

Comment: you've got to love python :p !

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the basic behavior. A `p`-length sub-vector from the first column of an indexing matrix `idx` is being used to select elements from `v` and place them into the same locations in the matrix `w` after first adjusting their values by the scalar `theta`.

It is critical to use one-based indexing for MATLAB and zero-based indexing for `numpy`.

In MATLAB,

```
clear

% Data matrices
w = zeros(5,5)
v = diag([10,20,30,40,50]) * ones(5,5)

% Indexing matrix
idx = ceil(5*rand(5, 5))

% Selection and adjustment parameters
p = 3    
theta = 1

% Apply adjustment and selection
w(idx(1:p, 1), 1) = v(idx(1:p, 1), 1) - theta
```

produces the output

```
w =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


v =

    10    10    10    10    10
    20    20    20    20    20
    30    30    30    30    30
    40    40    40    40    40
    50    50    50    50    50


idx =

     3     1     2     3     4
     1     1     2     1     3
     4     1     2     2     2
     1     1     5     1     1
     1     2     4     5     4


theta =

     1


p =

     3


w =

     9     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
    29     0     0     0     0
    39     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

And, the equivalent Python code using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

# Data arrays
w = np.zeros((5,5))
v = np.dot(np.diag([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]), np.ones((5,5)))
print "w = "
print w
print "v = "
print v

# Indexing array
idx = np.floor(5 * np.random.rand(5,5)).astype(int)
print "idx = "
print idx

# Selection and adjustment parameters
theta = 1
p = 3

# Apply selection and adjustment
w[idx[:p, 0], 0] = v[idx[:p, 0], 0] - theta
print "w = "
print w
```

which produces the output

```
w = 
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
v = 
[[ 10.  10.  10.  10.  10.]
 [ 20.  20.  20.  20.  20.]
 [ 30.  30.  30.  30.  30.]
 [ 40.  40.  40.  40.  40.]
 [ 50.  50.  50.  50.  50.]]
idx = 
[[0 2 2 0 3]
 [1 2 1 2 4]
 [2 2 4 3 4]
 [0 1 1 4 4]
 [0 1 0 4 3]]
w = 
[[  9.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 19.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 29.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```